# Define rowsource for ComboBox to be values in column A starting at A2

Tags: excel, vba

This is what i have tried so far,

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim WBK As Workbook

Set WBK = ActiveWorkbook
    WBK.Sheets("MFG_DATA").Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "Manufacturer"
Me.MFGBOX.RowSource = "Manufacturer"
End Sub
```

I'm getting an Error 1004, so I am not defining my object correctly?

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835300.aspx) on how to add a named range.  Then you call it with `Range("Manufacturer")`  If you want to use a temp variable then you need to use `Set Manufacturer = WBK.Sheets("MFG_DATA").Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` then do not use quotes on last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
WBK.Sheets("MFG_DATA").Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "Manufacturer"
```

Here `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` is not qualified with a worksheet object, and so will refer to the active sheet. If that's not "MFG_DATA" then you'll get an error.

Better to use:

```
With WBK.Sheets("MFG_DATA")
    .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "Manufacturer"
End with
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to use .AddItem method to populate combobox.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim WBK As Workbook
Dim n as Integer
Dim item() as String

Set WBK = ActiveWorkbook
n = WBK.Sheets("MFG_DATA").Range("A" & WBK.Sheets("MFG_DATA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Row

For i = 1 To n
  With Me.MFGBOX
    .AddItem item(i)
  End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Or if you want to use named range

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim cRng as Range
Dim cLoc As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim n as Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("MFG_DATA")

n = ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Row

Set cRng = ws.Range("A2:A" & n)
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Manufacturer", RefersTo:=cRng 

For Each cLoc In ws.Range("Manufacturer") 'or For Each cLoc In cRng
  With Me.MFGBOX
    .AddItem cLoc.Value
  End With
Next cLoc

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @B. Peulic, For some reason this triggers an error 1004 on UserForm2.Show. This is the sub that opens the userform with the combo box in it.

Comment: @Geoff I tried to mimic your error, and it happened when cRng was invalid. Can you please check if your range starts at A2 and if there are any values in A column. Thing is, code is calculating total number of records in column A and creates a range. If there are none, range would be A2:A1, which is invalid range. You can augment the range so it starts at A1 till A & n, but it depends on the data you have and in which column it is (the one you want to use in your combobox).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of macro you can use named ranges, just create a table say "Table1" in column A add the combo box values from A2..An then it will come into the table range.

Then define the named range as **Combovalue** and specify the range as **=Table1[Headername]**, this will automatically get updated even if you adding new combobox values in the table.

Now in the combobox property give the named range name in **RowSource** proerty **Combovalue**, now run the form the named range values will be displayed in the combobox :)

Comment: Will this affect a loop I have that finds values in Column A?

Comment: Instead of the loop you use this method, please try it you will come to know